# App with white toolbar and dark text

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have been trying to achieve this in a project with **minSDK 16** :

> Actionbar and statusbar in White color with dark text and icons.

Like this:

[image]

I have been trying to figure this out for ages now. Google searches lead to a lot of answers that dont make any sense and/or dont support older api's. `colorControlNormal`, `titleTextColor`, Appcompat-this, Appcompat-that... its a nightmare!

I am also not able to find any docs on what items to put in my styles xml, and none of the combinations of style properties I tried seem to have any effect whatsoever.

So can someone please give me a proper and well explained walkthrough as to how I can acheive this effect?

Thanks.

Comment: your picture is for sure not a screenshot from an actual device, but rather a render. While this is for sure possible to change the ActionBar color, I don't think (at least I'm not aware of any solution) that it's possible to change the status bar color prior to SDK 19.

Answer (score 4):

you can try with that

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

but API min is 23.

Also, don't forget to use different styles for different versions of APIs so far I haven't found an app that works as you want, so most probably isn't possible.

Comment: I have also struggled with the same problem, and the above mentioned solution is the only solution I have been able to find yet. So, I am basically maintaining two `style.xml` files in my project, i.e. one for base and another one for `v23` and above. And in the base style, I have kept status bar colour as grey, so that white icons are visible. By the way nice question as I also wanted to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your Base Application Theme in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

And add following attribute to your parent layout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”
```

Comment: `android:windowTranslucentStatus` doesn't makes the status bar white on lollipop devices. Instead the status bar becomes translucent.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowLightStatusBar "...and the status bar must not have been requested to be translucent with windowTranslucentStatus."

Answer (score 0):

**You can customize your toolbar with custom view as follows:**

Create your view inside toolbar and use in you code as you want

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
      
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Java:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This will help you