# How to create a white toolbar with text and icons in custom color?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have to create a toolbar with a custom background color(nearly white) and all the elements on it(up-Button, menu-Buttons, title, etc.) need to have a custom color too (all of them the same custom color).

[App with white toolbar and dark text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363591/app-with-white-toolbar-and-dark-text) -> Answer 1 doesn't work because it only changes the StatusBar, not the toolbar and it only works since API level 23 instead of 21.

My current styles.xml file looks like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

The way it is now I can control the background color of the toolbar but I can't change the color of the elemnts on the toolbar.

I don't want to create a custom Toolbar because I don't want to change any of the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve it myself.

I added `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/toolbar_element_color</item>` to `AppTheme.ActionBar` and `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbar_element_color</item>` to `AppTheme`.

My styles.xml file now looks like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbar_element_color</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/toolbar_element_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: keep in mind colorControlNormal affects much more than just the toolbar

Comment: @Tim Castelijns it does? What else does it change and how could I do something similar without affecting anything other than the toolbar?

Answer (score -1):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackPress"
        style="@style/clickableStyle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:rotationY="@integer/locale_mirror_flip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:text="Custom Toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: where is the toolbar?

Comment: You have to create a custom XML file for above code,
Then include this file in your activity parent layout.